# Windows explorer hangs on screen resize

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

When I open a Windows Explorer screen (<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>) and I do any kind of resizing, I get this behaviour on a Windows 10 laptop:

1. Explorer windows falls to a minimum size

[image]

2. And the folder names flicker (can't show that).
3. I have to kill Explorer through task manager and restart to continue.

Afaik this is Explorer behaviour only. All other windows are fine.

> What's going on and how do I fix it?

Comment: What version of Windows.  Does this behavior happen in a minimal start-up configuration?  Please edit your question to provide this clarification.

Comment: @Ramhound: Updated.

Comment: A full system defragmentation with `defrag /C /H /U` works for my PC.

Answer (score 1):

### Method 1 (Clean Boot)

1. GO TO (windows + R). Type `msconfig` Enter.
2. Go to Services Tab. You Can see `Hide all Microsoft services` at bottom, click to select the check box, and then click in click `Disable all` button. Click on `Apply` Button.
3. Now Go to Startup Tab. Click on `Open Taskbar Manager` You get windows of Task Manager. For each startup item, select the item and then click Disable.
4. Once you Disabled all the Startup. Close the Taskbar Manager Window. and Click on OK of System Configuration Window. Restart Your System.

### Method 2(Remove Malicious Software)

1. You have to remove the Malicious software installed. and also make sure you are running latest windows 10 Build.
2. Click on this Link [MS Malicious](http://www.microsoft.com/security/scanner/en-us/default.aspx), Select the Version 32 Bit or 64 bit.
3. Download it and Scan your system. If any remove the Malicious Software's and msert.exe will remove those. Restart Your PC.

---

*IF above methods didn't work*

- I would like you verify your Graphic Drivers are up to Date. If no make it up to date.
- Try with Safe Mode Boot (You Find the option in msconfig -> boot tab ) and check whether you have same issue in safe mode also.

Comment: I tried method 2 but no difference (or malware, surely a good thing to know, though the opposite would have surprised me). Other actions I need to discuss with the sysadmins, because it's my work laptop. I can't just decide that on my own.  I'll keep you posted :).

Comment: Clean boot is good thing can do by Yourself. So Method 1 will only disable your startup unwanted services application once you start your laptop.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue, too. It has nothing to do with graphics driver, but with file preview in a right pane. If you disable the preview (in a full screen Explorer window go to 'View', click on 'Preview pane'), resize the window and switch the preview again, it should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

A temporary fix is to use the key combination Windows key + Ctrl + Shift + B

I think it resets the graphics driver. Note that your screens will go blank for a second.

Hopefully the issue is resolved in the new build being released soon.